# How Can I return adsense code from a function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Am calling the publisher id from the authors meta i.e `the_author_meta('pub-id', $author_id`

***CODE***

```
 //RECTANGLE Adsense UNit
function get_rectangle() {
    global $post; $author_id=$post->post_author;
$rec_Ad.= '<div>';
            $rec_Ad.= '<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
            <!-- 300x250 -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                 style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"';

    if (get_the_author_meta('rectangle', $author_id)) { 

                 $rec_Ad.= 'data-ad-client="ca-pub-'.the_author_meta('pub-id', $author_id).'"';
                 $rec_Ad.= 'data-ad-slot="'.the_author_meta('rectangle', $author_id).'"></ins>';
}
            $rec_Ad.= '<script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script></div>';
   }
```

The above code returns the publisher id but not the whole adsense code

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function get_rectangle()
{
    global $post; $author_id= $post->post_author;

    $rec_Ad = '<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>';

    <!-- 300x250 -->
    $rec_Ad .= '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"';

    if (get_the_author_meta('rectangle', $author_id)) {
        $rec_Ad .= 'data-ad-client="ca-pub-'. get_the_author_meta('pub-id', $author_id) .'"';
        $rec_Ad .= 'data-ad-slot="'. get_the_author_meta('rectangle', $author_id) .'"></ins>';
    }

    $rec_Ad .= '<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>';
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it returns this html code 
`91684956458900569117871855<div><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"data-ad-client="ca-pub-"
              data-ad-slot=""></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script></div>`

The numbers you see at the beginning are the `pub-id` and `slot` together

Comment: Just edited my answer. I think the problem was that `the_author_meta` was used insead of `get_the_author_meta` because it directly echos the value. See:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/